# Query for all smartphones in portrait orientation

Tags: iphone, css, media-queries, iphone-5

What im trying to achieve is a media query that will work **only** on all smartphone on portrait orentation

I was using so far this one, but it isnt working in iPhone 5. Why is this?

```
@media only screen and (max-width:800px) and (orientation: portrait){
    aside{ display: none;}
}
```

Comment: try :: (max-width:568px)

Answer (score 0):

iPhone 5 display resolution is 1136 x 640 pixels. Measuring 4 inches diagonally, the new touch screen has an aspect ratio of 16:9 and is branded a Retina display with 326 ppi (pixels per inch).

Try:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 560px) and (max-device-width: 1136px) {
   aside{ display: none;}
}
```

Comment: Are you using a real iPhone or an Emulator?

Comment: And what shows the Homepage, that your iPhone's resolution is? My Sony has 640x360 in the Chrome Browser.

Answer (score 0):

**All mobile screens in portrait:**

In CSS:

```
@media only screen and (max-device-aspect-ratio: 1) and (orientation: portrait) {
     aside{ display: none;}
}
```

**Small mobile screens in portrait with explicitly set viewport width:**

Declare this scaling mode in HTML `<head>`

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

In CSS:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 479px) and (max-device-aspect-ratio: 1) and (orientation: portrait) {
     aside{ display: none;}
}
```

**All mobile screens in portrait with default viewport width (980px):**

Note: It has become standard practice in modern web design to define your viewport width instead of leaving it at the default 980px. It is integral to [Responsive Design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design). I strongly suggest taking some time to learn about it.

In CSS:

```
@media only screen and (width: 980px) and (max-device-aspect-ratio: 1) and (orientation: portrait) {
     aside{ display: none;}
}
```

Comment: Adding the meta tag makes that my page looks weird on the iPhone5. It just fills half the width of the screen

Comment: I updated the meta viewport tag to include initial scale, maybe that will make it look properly. Otherwise I added another solution below that you might be ok with